# Swift 5 - Error while assign property values of equal types through generic

Tags: swift, generics, constraints

```
class SQS_Record {
   var table: SQS_Table? = nil
}

class SQS_Table<RecordType: SQS_Record> {

   func newRecord() -> RecordType {
      let new = RecordType()
         new.table = self               <<< ERROR: 
         return new
      }
}
```

COMPILER ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'SQS_Table' to type 'SQS_Table<SQS_Record>'

In future i wish:

```
class Project: SQS_Record {
   var name: String = ""
}

let projectsTbl = SQS_Table<Project>(...)
```

and create object like this

```
let item = projectsTbl.newRecord()
```

Comment: This is correct since they are different types. Your design is hard to understand since you have a recursive reference to SQS_Table, could you explain in words what a table and what a record is in this context?

Comment: yes, i need to know - how to realize recursive reference between two classes. Class A has field of type B, class B has field of type A. And class B has generic type witch constranted to type A

Comment: It's hard to help when the design is unclear. And it's not really true what you write about A and B in your comment, A has a field of type B but B is generic and can hold a type A or a subclass of A. And this part is hard to understand so it would be good if you could supply some context.

Comment: The way you've written this, `SQS_Record.table` is always going to be exactly `SQS_Table<SQS_Record>`, for subclasses, for everything. It can't be anything else but that precise type. In practice, that means that `RecordType` will have to be `SQS_Record` in all cases. Again, it can't be anything else (not a subclass, nothing else). I don't think this is what you mean because this generic cannot actually be generic. I suspect you mean this to somehow be covarient? Mixing class inheritance and protocols this way is very tricky and unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: I highly suspect that you mean SQS_Record to be a protocol, not a class.

Comment: How does that even work? `var table: SQS_Table? = nil` should give a compilation error, as `SQS_Table` is a generic type... But strangely, there is no compiler error...

Answer (score 1):

Given what you've described, you're looking for protocols, not classes. For example:

```
// TableRecords know their table (and know other things)
// Note that TableRecord is a PAT (protocol with an associated type).
// There can not be any variables of type "TableRecord." It can only
// be used to constrain other types (as in Table below).
protocol TableRecord {
    init(table: Table<Self>)
    var table: Table<Self> { get }
}

// Project is a concrete TableRecord that also has a name.
// There can be variables of type Project.
struct Project: TableRecord {
    let table: Table<Self>

    var name: String = ""
    init(table: Table<Self>) {
        self.table = table
    }
}

// Tables can create new records of the Record type
class Table<Record: TableRecord> {
    func newRecord() -> Record {
        let new = Record(table: self)
        return new
    }
}

let projects = Table<Project>()
let item = projects.newRecord() // item is of type Project
```

Comment: let table: Table<Self>     Stored property cannot have covariant 'Self' type

Comment: You've made Project a class. If it's just data, then I recommend making it a struct as I did in my example. If you need a reference type, then you'll have to write `Table<Project>` here. Note that this is not covariant. You cannot subclass Project to get different types for `table`. That's why this is a protocol, not a class. You can't solve this problem with inheritance.

Comment: it must have Project as Class. Not struct. Bucause a need reference in memory - not copy data. Due to logic of other implementation. but i can make Table as struct. Is it possible?

Comment: Then use `Table<Project>` and mark it `final`. You cannot subclass Project in a meaningful way (generics cannot work that way), but it can be a class if that's needed.

Comment: class Record {}. class Project: Record{}. class Table{}. class ProjectsTable: Table {}

Comment: i can set - final class Table<RecordType: Record> {} . Is it right way?

Comment: It doesn't matter if `Table` is final or not. It's something that applies to the TableRecords.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to use generic type in recursive reference between two classes with inheritance
Whats why we need to do:

1. var table: AnyObject? - field can store any class (ref)
2. (table as! SQS_Table).reloadRecord(record: self as! Self) - exotic type cast based on Self.

I cant solve this problem with Protocol. Inheritance from reference type (Class - NOT struct) and type cast - prohibited

```
class SQS_Record {
   var table: AnyObject? = nil

   // Example - access to referenced table method and pass self param
   func reload() {
      guard __table != nil else { return }
      (table as! SQS_Table<Self>).reloadRecord(record: self as! Self)
   }

}

class SQS_Table<RecordType: SQS_Record> {

   // RecordType - subclass of SQS_Record

   func newRecord() -> RecordType {
      let new = RecordType()
         new.table = self               
         return new
      }

   func reloadRecord(record: RecordType) {
      ...
   }
}

class Project: SQS_Record {
   ...
}

let projectsTable = SQS_Table<Project>(...)

let newProjectRecord = projectsTable.newRecord()

newProjectRecord.reload()
```

Comment: You should add a description of this solution, code only answers are discouraged

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Is this the answer? It looks more like a second question.